# Sort Sequential Guids Generated by UuidCreateSequential

Tags: c#, guid

I tried to sort Guids generated by UuidCreateSequential, but I see the results are not correct, am I mising something? here is the code

```
    private class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);
    }

    public static Guid CreateSequentialGuid()
    {
        const int RPC_S_OK = 0;

        Guid guid;
        int result = NativeMethods.UuidCreateSequential(out guid);
        if (result == RPC_S_OK)
            return guid;
        else throw new Exception("could not generate unique sequential guid");
    }

    static void TestSortedSequentialGuid(int length)
    {
        Guid []guids = new Guid[length];
        int[] ids = new int[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            guids[i] = CreateSequentialGuid();
            ids[i] = i;
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }

        Array.Sort(guids, ids);

        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (ids[i] > ids[i + 1])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("sorting using guids failed!");
                return;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("sorting using guids succeeded!");
    }
```

EDIT1:

Just to make my question clear, why the guid struct is not sortable using the default comparer ?

EDIT 2: 
Also here are some sequential guids I've generated, seems they are not sorted ascending as presented by the hex string

```
            "53cd98f2504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "7178df9d504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "800b5b69504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "9796eb73504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "c14c5778504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "c14c5779504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "d2324e9f504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "d2324ea0504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "da3d4460504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "e149ff28504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "f2309d56504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "f2309d57504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "fa901efd504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "fa901efe504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "036340af504b11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "11768c0b504b11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "2f57689d504b11e682838cdcd43024a7"
```

Comment: Running your exact sample, im able to generate sequential guids on x86. Cant reproduce. please tell more about system-settings

Comment: you need to have long sleep for each iteration, with that sleep, ya they are sorted

Comment: Nope... Removed your sleep. everything still fine. Result see [here](http://pastebin.com/wg4YTQLE)

Comment: Sorry I meant with sleep it does not work

Comment: Is there any special reason to wait a minute to generate a guid? I'm really not willing to wait now 10 minutes to reproduce that. But i think, its not working this way because the sequence might get interrupted on such long breaks

Comment: You know the answer to your question, you just don't realize it yet. According to your statement and the statement of the other commenters, the program has different behaviour depending on whether there is a wait of a minute between calls.  Therefore *something must be happening in that minute*.  What do you suppose could be happening in that time which would change the behaviour of a *sequential* guid generator?

Comment: thread.sleep is just simulate the behavior of users' requests. to verify the guids are sequential over a long period.

Comment: @AhmedSaid: You're not thinking this through.  Here, tell you what, you be the service which provides sequential numbers any time someone asks.  I'm going to ask you for ten sequential numbers in the next minute.  Now I'm going to wait forty years until I ask you again. What do you suppose might have happened to you in that intervening 40 years. Hint: maybe I am not the only person asking you for sequential numbers in that time. Now combine this with the fact that the U stands for "unique", and what do you conclude?

Comment: @EricLippert let me rephrase my question to understand your comment, does UUIDCreateSequential guarantee the global uniqueness and sequentiality of the generated guids as it uses machine time internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, I can't sort the guid using the default sort or even using the default string representation from guid.ToString as the byte order is different.

to sort the guids generated by UuidCreateSequential I need to convert to either BigInteger or form my own string representation (i.e. hex string 32 characters) by putting bytes in most signification to least significant order as follows:

```
static void TestSortedSequentialGuid(int length)
{
    Guid []guids = new Guid[length];
    int[] ids = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        guids[i] = CreateSequentialGuid();
        ids[i] = i;

// this simulates the delay between guids creation
// yes the guids will not be sequential as it interrupts generator 
// (as it used the time internally) 
// but still the guids should be in increasing order and hence they are     
// sortable and that was the goal of the question
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }

        var sortedGuidStrings = guids.Select(x =>
        {
            var bytes = x.ToByteArray();

          //reverse high bytes that represents the sequential part (time)            
            string high = BitConverter.ToString(bytes.Take(10).Reverse().ToArray());

             //set last 6 bytes are just the node (MAC address) take it as it is.
                return high + BitConverter.ToString(bytes.Skip(10).ToArray());
        }).ToArray();

    // sort ids using the generated sortedGuidStrings
    Array.Sort(sortedGuidStrings, ids);

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (ids[i] > ids[i + 1])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sorting using sortedGuidStrings failed!");
            return;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("sorting using sortedGuidStrings succeeded!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, let's re-state the observation: when creating sequential GUIDs with a huge time delay -- 60 *billion* nanoseconds -- between creations, the resulting GUIDs are not sequential.

> am I missing something?

You know every fact you need to know to figure out what is going on. You're just not putting them together.

You have a service that provides numbers which are both *sequential* and *unique across all computers in the universe*.  Think for a moment about how that is possible. It's not a magic box; someone had to write that code.

Imagine if you didn't have to do it using computers, but instead had to do it by hand.  You advertise a service: you provide *sequential globally unique numbers* to *anyone* who asks at *any time*.

Now, suppose I ask you for three such numbers and you hand out  20, 21, and 22.  Then *sixty years later* I ask you for three more and surprise, you give me 13510985, 13510986 and 13510987.  "Wait just a minute here", I say, "I wanted six sequential numbers, but you gave me three sequential numbers and then three more.  What gives?"

Well, what do you suppose happened in that intervening 60 years?  Remember, you provide this service to *anyone who asks, at any time*.  Under what circumstances could you give me 23, 24 and 25?  **Only if no one else asked within that 60 years**.

Now is it clear why your program is behaving exactly as it ought to?

In practice, the sequential GUID generator uses the current time as part of its strategy to enforce the globally unique property. Current time and current location is a reasonable starting point for creating a unique number, since presumably there is only one computer on your desk at any one time.

Now, I caution you that this is only a starting point; suppose you have twenty virtual machines all in the same real machine and all trying to generate sequential GUIDs at the same time? In these scenarios collisions become much more likely. You can probably think of techniques you might use to mitigate collisions in these scenarios.

Comment: as far as I understand it uses MAC address to guarantee uniqueness and the time to guarantee the sequentiality,

Comment: "You have a service that provides numbers which are both sequential and unique across all computers in the universe ... It's not a magic box; someone had to write that code." - I thought there was a [demon](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) that generated all the numbers!

Comment: the question is about the sorted guids not the sequential pattern. so the generated guids are not sorted using the default guid sort

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood your question correctly. It seems you are trying to sort the HEX representation of your Guids. That really means that you are sorting them *alphabetically* and not *numerically*.

Guids will be indexed by their byte value in the database. Here is a console app to prove that your Guids are numerically sequential:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //These are the sequential guids you provided.
        Guid[] guids = new[]
        {
            "53cd98f2504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "7178df9d504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "800b5b69504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "9796eb73504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "c14c5778504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "c14c5779504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "d2324e9f504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "d2324ea0504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "da3d4460504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "e149ff28504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "f2309d56504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "f2309d57504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "fa901efd504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "fa901efe504a11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "036340af504b11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "11768c0b504b11e682838cdcd43024a7",
            "2f57689d504b11e682838cdcd43024a7"
        }.Select(l => Guid.Parse(l)).ToArray();

        //Convert to BigIntegers to get their numeric value from the Guids bytes then sort them.
        BigInteger[] values = guids.Select(l => new BigInteger(l.ToByteArray())).OrderBy(l => l).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++)
        {
            //Convert back to a guid.
            Guid sortedGuid = new Guid(values[i].ToByteArray());

            //Compare the guids. The guids array should be sequential.
            if(!sortedGuid.Equals(guids[i]))
                throw new Exception("Not sequential!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All good!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: so I can't sort the guids using the default comparer ? the UUIDCreateSequential returns sequential guid, I thought I can sort them using the default guid comparer